# Can't deselect item in collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview, didselectrowatindexpath, pfcollectionviewcell

i have collectionView. At the first launch I change color for first item to black. The problem is that when I select another item I want it to become black and first item become white. I use didSelectItemAtIndexPath and didDeselectItemAtIndexPath, but if i don't click the first item then I can't change it's color when I click another one. Can someone help me?

Comment: I just added collectionView.selectItem method in cellForRow for first item and everything works nice

Answer (score 1):

set a selectedindexpath and reload collection view according to selected index path.

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

var selectedIndexPath : IndexPath?

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "identifier", for: indexPath)
    if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
    return cell
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by following way.

Override the method in UICollectionViewCell Class like below

```
override var isSelected: Bool{
    didSet{
        if(self.isSelected){
            yourView.backgroundColor = YourSelectedColor

        }else{
            yourView.backgroundColor = YourUnSelectedColor
        }
    }
}
```

No Need to do anything in didSelectItemAt or didDeSelectItemAt methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your element from your data source array should somehow know about current state of cell. For example you can have property of your custom object:

```
var isSelected: Bool = false
```

in `didSelectItemAt` method first change every element's `isSelected` property to `false` and then for selected element set `true` and then reload data of `collectionView`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    dataSourceArray.forEach { $0.isSelected = false }
    dataSourceArray[indexPath.row] = true
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

then in `cellForRowAt` change `backgroundColor` of `cell` depends on `isSelected` property of certain element in your data source array

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    ...
    cell.backgroundColor = dataSourceArray[indexPath.row] ? .black : .white
    ...
}
```

---

```
var selectedIndexPath = IndexPath?
```

Alternatively you can just save `indexPath` of selected cell as global variable

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

and then in `cellForRowAt` you can set `backgroundColor` of cell depends on condition if `indexPath` is equal to `selectedIndexPath`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    ...
    cell.backgroundColor = indexPath == selectedIndexPath ? .black : .white
    ...
}
```